# what this replace function do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across some javascript code like this:

```
selector = $this.attr('href')
selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '')
```

And I don't quite understand what the replace part do.Can someone explain that in detail?

Thanks,G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It replaces `selector` variable using RegEx.

`/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/` replaces anchor to empty string and perhaps return domain name of page where you in. For example http://example.com/text.php

I've made and example http://jsfiddle.net/9j5Sn/

Comment: @Gnijuohz, if he's right, vote it up and mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @JamesHill ok,I kind of expect him to explain how it works.Especially the RegEx part as I am new to it.Yeah,he is right and I'd like to mark  it as the answer.